# Is there anyway to make Kendo use a Named Template?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have one class that I use it for two different purposes and on each use case some different fields should be shown, some are editables and some are read only.

I'm using Kendo Grid to show them and I want customized create and edit modal windows for each use case.

Perhaps the only solution is to build different editor templates. Do I have any way to make Kendo Grid use different editor templates? Any option other than using ViewModels?

Comment: Can you the post the code ?

Comment: Code of what? The Grid?

Comment: What all you have tried ?, we can't give a solution without knowing where the problem lies

Comment: I haven't really tried anything yet! I'm just asking what should I do? Can I make Kendo grid to use an editor template that I'm going to build? Or my only change is to create an editor template with the name of my class, which means I should use different view models to have different layouts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Grid does not support setting multiple popup editor templates. Possible solution would be to add all of the editors in a single template and use the [edit event](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#events-edit) of the Grid to hide/remove the ones that are not needed depending on the current operation - create/update.

```
function onEdit(e){
    if(e.model.isNew()){
        //operation is create
        e.container.find(...).remove();
    } else {
        //operation is update
    }
}
```